# How to use NFC and iOS13 to call contactless payment machine without apple pay?

Tags: nfc, ios13

I want to build a payment app by NFC and iOS13 to send/receive data from contactless payment machine for a country not support apple pay, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to work with NFC at iOS is [Core NFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc

You can read tags and get some special Informations. For example to get information about a product.

In my opinion Apple blocks the data evaluation of payments. So you can only use the Core NFC.